# Theme not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have set the app theme in styles.xml to AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar but it is not hiding the action bar in the visual editor.

This is the Styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Its a `status-bar` not `actionbar`

Comment: Doesn't work. This is the error: https://imgur.com/a/IlqB6u3

Answer (score 1):

you can use this if you want to hide status bar.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Also Add this in for your  activity in manifest

```
<activity
   android:name=".activities.FullViewActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

Comment: That does not work. This is the error that I get: https://imgur.com/a/FrOh4Gc

Comment: @EthanAdamsI have changed my solution for you check this out. It should do your work